# How to fix error "this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []"

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I used to work for glassfish. Switched to tomee. It turns out this error, what is the problem? I did everything according to the instructions and I do not know what the reason.

This is server.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/chessman_work" 
              auth="Container" 

              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
              classpath="${basedir}/lib/mysql-connector.jar" 

              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chessman_work?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useSSL=false"

              username="root" 
              password="root"

              maxActive="100" 
              maxIdle="30" 
              maxWait="10000" />
```

context.xml:

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/chessman_work" global="jdbc/chessman_work" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

log:

```
12-Jan-2019 12:59:37.210 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in 25381 ms
12-Jan-2019 12:59:37.656 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState.stop HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chessman_work?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false]
12-Jan-2019 12:59:37.675 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: F:\Developer\Programms\Chessman\ChessmanWork\target\ChessmanWork
12-Jan-2019 12:59:38.088 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ChessmanWork] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
12-Jan-2019 12:59:38.090 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ChessmanWork] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:70)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
12-Jan-2019 12:59:38.607 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Undeploying context [/ChessmanWork]
12-Jan-2019 12:59:38.651 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying deployment descriptor [F:\Servers\apache-tomee-plume-8.0.0-M1\conf\Catalina\localhost\ChessmanWork.xml]
12-Jan-2019 12:59:38.658 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke The path attribute with value [/ChessmanWork] in deployment descriptor [F:\Servers\apache-tomee-plume-8.0.0-M1\conf\Catalina\localhost\ChessmanWork.xml] has been ignored
12-Jan-2019 12:59:38.660 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /ChessmanWork
12-Jan-2019 12:59:38.838 INFO [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1006)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```